# Inheritance of first countable space $X$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a first-countable space and $A \subset X$. Show that $A$ is first-countable.

Pick $a \in A$. Then since $a \in X$ there exists countable local basis $\mathcal{B}_a$ such that $\forall B \in \mathcal{B}_a :a \in B$ and for open $O \subset X$ if $a \in O$, then $\exists B \in \mathcal{B}_a : B \subset O$.

Doesn't the result follow here immediately? Why wouldn't a basis for $X$ be a basis for $A$ if $A$ is a subspace of $X$?

I know that we can characterize a basis for subspace as $\mathcal{B}_A = \{B \cap A \mid B \in \mathcal{B}_X\}$, and what I could do is argue that from a countable local basis $\mathcal{B}_a$ of $X$ I can construct a countable local basis $\mathcal{B}_a'$, but why should I do that if I already have a satisfactory basis for $X$ that serves as the basis for $A$ also?

Comment: The problem is that a countable local basis $\mathcal{B}_a$ at $a$ for $X$ may contain sets which are not contained in $A$. For examples, take $X$ to be the plane and $A$ to be the $x$-axis. Then the set of all open disks centered at the origin with rational radius is a countable local basis at the origin for $X$, but it is not a countable local basis at the origin for $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Just note that if $\mathcal{B}_a$ is a local base at $a$ for $X$, then $\{B \cap A\mid B \in \mathcal{B}_a\}$ is a local base at $a$ for $A$. Trivial from the definitions.

Comment: The intersections with $A$ are needed to get open sets in $A$ from open sets in $X$, of course.